# Sorting computed data in laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting

So I am working on filter API for an e-commerce application. I have finished doing filtering data with a query to get the product model and passed the collection to the product resource to generate JSON resource with computed data.
This is my query:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('brand')->where('products.status', '1')
        ->leftJoin('attribute_products', 'products.id', '=', 'attribute_products.product_id')
        ->leftJoin('brands', 'products.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
        ->leftJoin('category_products', 'category_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->leftJoin('categories', 'category_products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->where('attribute_products.stock', '!=', 0)
        ->where(function ($query) use ($filterparams, $parts) {
            if ($filterparams['search_query']) {
                foreach ($parts as $part) {
                    $query->where('products.slug', 'like', '%' . $part . '%')
                        ->orWhere('products.name', 'like', '%' . $part . '%')
                        ->orWhere('brands.name', 'like', '%' . $part . '%')
                        ->orWhere('brands.slug', 'like', '%' . $part . '%')
                        ->orWhere('categories.name', 'like', '%' . $part . '%')
                        ->orWhere('categories.slug', 'like', '%' . $part . '%');
                }
            }
            if ($filterparams['brands']) {
                $query->whereIn('products.brand_id', $filterparams['brands']);
            }
            if ($filterparams['category_id']) {
                $query->whereIn('category_products.category_id', $filterparams['category_id']);
            }
            if ($filterparams['attribute_id']) {
                $query->whereIn('attribute_products.attribute_id', $filterparams['attribute_id']);
            }
            if ($filterparams['featured'] == 1) {
                $query->where('products.featured', 1);
            }
            if ($filterparams['trending'] == 1) {
                $query->where('products.trending', 1);
            }
            if ($filterparams['min_price']) {
                $query->where('attribute_products.price', '>=', $filterparams['min_price']);
            }
            if ($filterparams['max_price']) {
                $query->where('attribute_products.price', '<=', $filterparams['max_price']);
            }
            if ($filterparams['discount_percent']) {
                $query->where('attribute_products.allow_discount', '1');
                $query->where('attribute_products.discount_type', 'percent');
                $query->whereDate('attribute_products.discount_from', '<=', date('Y-m-d', time()));
                $query->whereDate('attribute_products.discount_to', '>=', date('Y-m-d', time()));
                $query->where('attribute_products.discount_value', '<=', $filterparams['discount_percent']);
            }
            if ($filterparams['is_todays_deal']) {
                $query->whereHas('todaysDeal');
            }
        })
        ->orderBy($filterparams['sorting_key'], $filterparams['sorting_direction'])
        ->select('products.id as id', 'products.name as name', 'products.main_image as main_image')
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->paginate(10);
```

from this I have generated Resouce collection

```
$products = new ProductCollection($products);
```

this is how my JSON response looks like:

```
     [
        {
            "id": 2693,
            "name": "Product A",
            "coverImage": "http://abc.url/storage/product/cover_image1584083807.PNG",
            "wishlist": false,
            "attributeProductId": 5204,
            "type": "none",
            "stockQuantity": 10,
            "price": 900,
            "discountedPrice": 900,
            "isDiscounted": false,
            "discountPercent": 0,
            "ratingAndReview": {
                "total": 4,
                "averageRating": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2182,
            "name": "Product B",
            "coverImage": "http://abc.url/storage/product/cover_image1576822643.jpg",
            "wishlist": false,
            "attributeProductId": 4566,
            "type": "none",
            "stockQuantity": 22,
            "price": 465,
            "discountedPrice": 465,
            "isDiscounted": false,
            "discountPercent": 0,
            "ratingAndReview": {
                "total": 10,
                "averageRating": 3.5
            }
        }
      ]
```

Here "discountedPrice", "isDiscounted", "ratingAndReview" are computed in Product Resource and I want to sort the data with those key-values.
I tried this method:

```
$unsortedData  = json_decode($products->toJson(), true);
$sortedData = collect($unsortedData['products'])->sortBy('ratingAndReview.total', SORT_REGULAR, true);
```

This method does work but the response speed of the API will be very high and even I need to send data with custom pagination. so calling the API every time for pagination will make the application too slow.

What could be the solution to this? Please suggest to me if there are other best ways to achieve the same result in an efficient way?
Thank you.

Comment: Pagination and sorting / searching requires you to do it SQL based, else the pagination will have weird sideeffects can you show how you generate that data? Then we can make the SQL version of that.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have added my Query. Please do look into it once. 
And Currently, I have used scheduling to store those computed data and getting results after joining that table and sorting with those data. It is working but is it a good decision to choose that option?

Comment: Was more interested in how ratingAndReview.total is it based on some relationship data or how do you calculate it?

Comment: well Product model has many relationship with ProductReview. and it is simply calculated by $product->reviews()->count(); this calculation is done in product resource.